# Java Web Start & proxyPort/proxyHost

Tags: java, proxy, jnlp, java-web-start

my jws app is ignoring the proxy settings using the code like System.setProperty("proxyPort", value) etcp.

Starting the application just by using the jar except the jnlp, the proxy will be setted.

Whats the reason behind?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the property being set is classed as a 'trusted property'.  If that is the case then the JNLP will need to declare `all-permissions` in the `security` element.

It might also mean even that the JNLP file itself has to be included in the Jar & digitally signed along with the code.  I am a little fuzzy on when that applies.